# How to create Task with multiple params, return typ, TaskCreationOptions param by using new keyword?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

How can i create new task with multiple params, return type and createoptions by using new?

```
Task<int> task = Task<int>(DoWork(0,1));

private static Task<int> DoWork(int a, int b)
{
    return null;
}
```

this is working fine.... but when i try create task with new keyword so i can set startoptions to longrunning like this:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(DoWork(0,1), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

I am always getting some errs like:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Func'

I tried xx different variants but no luck. I understand i am probably wrongly passing param "Func function". I would like to avoid anonymous function. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the method as a `Lambda Expression`:

```
Task<Task<int>> task = new Task<Task<int>>(() => DoWork(0,1), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Although, it is recommended to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` if possible, so you return a `Hot Task` instead of a `Cold Task` (which required you to call `Task.Start`).

```
Task<Task<int>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(0,1), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: `DoWork` returns a `Task<int>` not an `int` so this won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SomeClass()
{
    var func = new Func<int, int, int>((i1, i2) => i1 + i2);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        Debug.WriteLine(func(1, 2)), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        Debug.WriteLine(DoWork(2, 3).Result), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

private static Task<int> DoWork(int a, int b)
{
    return Task.FromResult(a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321470.aspx) for `Task<T>` requires a `Func<T>` argument.

```
Task<int> task = Task<int>(DoWork(0,1));
```

is attempting to call the `DoWork` method and pass the returned`Task<int>` as the parameter into the `task` task. You need to pass a `Func<int>` instead by changing the type of `DoWork` to:

```
private static int DoWork(int a, int b) { ... }
```

then you can do:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => DoWork(0,1), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```